# Mahindra KUV 100 and Suzuki Alto OBD protocol

Tags: obd-ii, diesel, scan-tool

Can someone please tell me the OBD-II protocol of Mahindra KUV 100 (diesel) and Suzuki Alto (diesel).

Also whether ELM 327 Bluetooth will work?

http://www.ebay.in/itm/SuperMini-ELM-327-Bluetooth-v2-1-mini-EOBD-2-CAN-BUS-OBD2-CAR-Reader-Scanner-/111193354036

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more than the bare minimum on your questions.  If you take a little extra time and put in a little more info, they will get more attention.  The reason some of these just sit is that you know the rules by now.  Give us a make/model/year.  Help us help you.  We want to but this question......Can you put another calorie or two into it's creation......PLEASE.....thanks....